# Issue with Zalando Postgres operator configuration for logical backup

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-operator

The `vaule-crd.yaml` has the [pod_environment_configmap](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator/blob/32e6c135b9b387ad4f158f1b30fe0e3d151a364f/charts/postgres-operator/values-crd.yaml#L132) option which injects a configmap data into every database pod as environment variables.

Does this option also work for all cron jobs managed by the operator?
For now, I have to hardcode the S3 credentials in [configLogicalBackup](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator/blob/32e6c135b9b387ad4f158f1b30fe0e3d151a364f/charts/postgres-operator/values-crd.yaml#L264) section, like `logical_backup_s3_access_key_id`, `logical_backup_s3_secret_access_key`. Do the logical backup pods share the environments defined in `pod_environment_configmap`?